# QGIS - delete polys based on vector line layer - possible?

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing

I have a layer of polygons and a layer of vector lines.  I want to delete any poly that is touched/crossed/intersects a vector line.  Is this possible?

I have tried the Geoprocessing Tools.  Looks like I want 'Difference' but the best I can do is delete segments of lines that touch polys.  I want the opposite.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily achieve this using the spatial query plugin.

First you select all polygon features that intersect the lines layer. Then you can delete the selection